# Template with each page divided in three parts

Tags: templates

I'm looking for a template where each page of the document is divided in three sections. The upper half of the page is divided in two columns, with the left column being a quote of some original text, and the right column some comments associated to specific parts of the text on the left. The lower half of the page contains "free format" text.

The following is an image with two sample pages:

[image]

(In response to David comment)

The bottom half text flows automatically. The upper class is defined by the user. Note that the height of the upper half in each page can vary from page to page. The following picture illustrates this situation.

[image]

Is there a latex template or an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: do you need text to flow from the top right of one page to the top right of the next, or can the top half be two minipages with text broken (by hand). I'm assuming the bottom half is the main flow with text automatically flowing from bottom of one page to bottom half of next.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added more information to the question to address your comment.

Comment: Perhaps the [flowfram package](http://ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) can adjust for the layout you want to create belong your pictures. If not, perhaps the [tufte-latex](http://ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex) lets you to write in one narrow column with notes in the side and an environment called `\fullwidth` for wide text blocks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\def\a{\stepcounter{enumi}One two three four \roman{enumi} five six seven eight. }
\def\b{\a\a\a\a Red blue yellow. \a\a\a\a\a\ Green black blue \Roman{enumi}. }
\def\c{\b\b\b\par\a\b\a\b\a\par}

\def\z{ Interesting text that has notes attached}
\def\zz{\z\z\z\z\z}

\newcommand\mynote[1]{\strut\vadjust{%
\setbox0\hbox{\parbox[t]{.4\otextwidth}{#1}}%
\noindent
\raisebox{\dp\strutbox}[0pt][0pt]{\rlap{\hskip.6\otextwidth\box0\hss}}}}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{1}
\renewcommand\topfraction{.8}
\newlength\otextwidth
\setlength\otextwidth{\textwidth}

\newenvironment{thingy}
{\begin{figure}\begin{minipage}{.4\otextwidth}\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}}
{\end{minipage}\bigskip\end{figure}}


\begin{document}

\c
\begin{thingy}
\z\mynote{something}

\zz\mynote{something else very interesting side note

a bit longer this time}
\end{thingy}

xxx\
\begin{thingy}
\zz\mynote{somethin else about this textg}

\zz\zz\mynote{something else very interesting side note

a bit longer this time}
\end{thingy}

\c\c

\end{document}
```